# SQL - Query conditional from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I am trying to find the moments in which `column5` data is greater than `column6`. The following command works for me for results in one table

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column5 > column6;
```

But I would like to query a return from other tables using the same conditional `column5 > column6` and still select all because some columns provide additional  relevant information and reference. For example, something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE column5 > column6;
```

but I get an error complaining from an ambiguous named table `column5`... I switched the command over to something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.column5 > table1.column6 AND table2.column5 > table2.column6;
```

The above command does not produce and error but the query returns an empty result. I have also tried the INNER JOIN command as such

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.seconds = table2.seconds AND table1.column5 > table1.column6 AND table2.column5 > table2.column6;
```

This yields a result that is similar to the first command but the query results in all rows from table1 from that operator conditional repeated twice in the same row, but table2 results are not shown.

Is there another way to achieve this? Most of my attempts did not return the desired results. Again, I just wanted my query to result the rowid of multiple tables `WHERE *.column5 > *.column6`

[.sql file of the database pasted on codeshare.io to provide sample-data to this problem](https://codeshare.io/5emv4L)

Put sample data here:

```
Table1:
Column5    
"139062.6"
"115080"
"279718.5"
"106184"
"109483"
"152253"
"159030.3333"
"144092.5"
"154913.8333"
"52166.83333"
"18257.5"
"8907"

Column6
"224340.8"
"154723.6667"
"202486.8333"
"107184.8333"
"110674"
"257038.6667"
"151057"
"190702.6667"
"229714"
"37816.16667"
"18061.83333"
"6606.666667"

Table2:
Column5    
"7544.6"
"10165.16667"
"11574.16667"
"9400.833333"
"11421.5"
"11368.5"
"11925.83333"
"9108.833333"
"8276.666667"
"8650.5"
"14998.16667"
"16229.83333"

Column6
"10109"
"14526.83333"
"12070.66667"
"7819.333333"
"9247.833333"
"7201.833333"
"8166.833333"
"4928"
"9135.5"
"9666.166667"
"8201.166667"
"10186"     

Expected Result "WHERE column5 > column6" on table 1 and 2:

    TABLE 1      
Column5      
"279718.5"   
"159030.3333"
"52166.83333"
"18257.5"    
"8907"       

  Column6     
"202486.8333" 
"151057"      
"37816.16667" 
"18061.83333" 
"6606.666667" 


    TABLE 2 
  Column5        
 "9400.833333"    
 "11421.5"          
 "11368.5"      
"11925.83333"       
 "9108.833333"    
 "14998.16667"      
  "16229.83333"     

Column6

"7819.333333"
"9247.833333"
"7201.833333"
"8166.833333"
"4928"
"8201.166667"
"10186"
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result please.

Comment: I updated the question with a link for the sample data at the bottom.  Please disconsider table1. The expected result for querying the conditional WHERE column5 > column6 should be something like "00:00:10-00:00:15" "812367.8333" "381901.6667" "188617.8333" "279718.5" "202486.8333" "207844.5" "199836" "95699.83333" "" ""  "00:00:10-00:00:15" "736087.5" "142037.5" "18376.16667" "13577.83333" "11524.66667" "13789" "6587.833333" "5084.833333"

Comment: We cannot read minds. Please also put sample data on table1 and table2 and how the result will look like. I cannot open your link as well. It says "over capacity". Paste your sample data and expected result in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the union operator (assuming your tables have the same number of columns):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column5 > column6 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column5 > column6;
```

If you only want the rowids listed, `SELECT rowid` instead (it depends on how you want to use the result of the query later, as this way you have no way of telling which table the rowid refers to).

Comment: This command does produce the exact number of rows I am looking for but I still have the following issue; moments where column5 > column6 happens in both tables, the data seems to be summed. Also, there is no way of discerning which tables the results belong to, is there a way of achieve that?

Comment: A simple way would be to do `SELECT rowid, "table 1" AS origin FROM table1 UNION SELECT rowid, "table 2" AS origin FROM table2...` to distinguish between the origin tables of results. As for your other issue, I'm afraid I don't understand. Are you sure you are using the right WHERE clauses for the right tables? Or do you maybe only want to select distinct values from the tables?

Comment: SELECT rowid, "table 1" AS origin FROM table1 UNION SELECT rowid, "table 2" AS origin FROM table2... command worked perfectly for me ! This solved my issue